# Get correct height of tableview in popover after an additional cell is shown/hidden

Tags: ios, uitableview, uipopovercontroller

I'm displaying an `UITableView` in a `UIPopoverController`. This table view hides/shows some cells if another cell is tapped (compare with [this tutorial](http://masteringios.com/blog/2013/11/18/ios-7-in-line-uidatepicker-part-2/2/)). Because it is in a popover I want to adapt the size of the popover. Therefore I want to use an animation with `preferredContentSize`.

The problem now is that if I calculate the `contentSize` I don't get the actual size, because `heightForRowAtIndexPath` is called afterwards. I need the table view height after the table view has been reloaded or detect the change in height of the table view.

How can I get the correct height of the table view to adapt the size of the popover?

**Possible workarounds:**

1. scroll at the position of the new cell
2. never hides the cells
3. show popover in full size
4. manually calculate the sizes

But all workarounds has some disadvantages/limitations. No. 1 doesn't looks nice, No. 2 doesn't work well for me in landscape mode (other content can be overlooked), No. 3 doesn't looks nice and also other content can be overlooked and No. 4 would work if I'm aware of all possible cases.

Still looking for a better solution.

Comment: How about numberOfRows + hightOfRow?

Comment: Manually calculating the table view height would be an option. I thought onto some automatic calculations like `contentSize`. Another workaround would be to use `scrollToRowAtIndexPath`. The approaches I've seen to detect the finished loading event didn't worked for me (`willDisplayCell`, `didEndDisplayingCell`, ...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only manually calculating the height did it for me. My code is in C# and this is what I did:

I used a class variable where I stored the actual height. In `viewDidLoad` I have this

```
TableView.LayoutIfNeeded ();
height = TableView.ContentSize.Height;
this.PreferredContentSize = new SizeF (320f, height);
```

In `showDatePickerCell` and in `hideDatePickerCell` I calculate the new height and set it for the popover:

```
UIView.Animate (
    0.25,
    animation: () => {
        height += 206f;
        this.PreferredContentSize = new SizeF (320f, height);
    }
);
```

Now the popover expands and shrinks as desired.